# Examples using "народ" versus "люди"

Tags: лексикон, выбор-слова, синонимы

What are the differences in usage between *народ* and *люди*? I'd like to see some examples to explain such differences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Люди* is simply the plural of *человек*, and it means *people* in the sense of "more than one person".

*Народ* has several meanings. It can mean exactly the same as люди.

> В комнате было много людей.
>   В комнате было много народа.

*Народ* can mean a nation or an ethnic group (i. e. *a people*)

> Русский народ.
>   Украинский народ.
>   Международная конференция.

It can also mean the regular citizens, the working people, the lower classes, as opposed to the ruling elite or the aristocracy:

> Он вышел из народа.
>   "Узок круг этих революционеров. Страшно далеки они от народа." (В. И. Ленин)

Answer (score 4):

In Russian, *народ* means both "people" and "nation".

The word itself looks like a calque from Latin *natio* ("that which has been born"), and Vasmer mentions a dialectal usage "a mob, a herd of cattle". Probably the two have been formed independently (to mean "nation" and "people" accordingly), and later merged.

Duke Vyazemsky, a contemporary to Pushkin, mentions:

> Всякий грамотный человек знает, что слово *национальный* не существует в нашем языке; что у нас слово *народный* отвечает одно двум французским словам: *populaire* и *national*, что мы говорим: *песни народные* и *дух народный* там, где французы сказали бы: *chanson populaire* и *esprit national*. *[Дамский журн., 1824, 6, № 8]*

So in the meaning of "people", *народ* is pretty synonymous to *люди*, "men and women" (or its synecdoche *люд*), when the context assumes "group of people".

> Тебе на эстраде выступать надо, народ веселить. *[Я желанна. Разве это стыдно? // «Даша», 2004]*
>
> Смотри, держись хорошо, ― сказал он вдруг серьёзно, ― мужчины ― народ хитрый и не говорят того, что думают. *[Э. Г. Казакевич. Звезда (1946)]*

In the examples above, you can replace *народ* with *люди*.

If the context assumes individuals (as opposed to "group of people") then you can only use *люди*:

> А я хочу сказать, что люди в наше время разучились любить. *[А. И. Куприн. Гранатовый браслет (1911)]*
>
> ― Я всегда говорила, что у всех людей есть родители, кроме меня. *[Н. А. Тэффи. Семейный аккорд (1910)]*
>
> Безобразные сцены происходили между этими людьми, которые в течение десяти лет избегали резкого выражения, резкого движения. *[В. Я. Брюсов. Через пятнадцать лет (1909)]*

In the examples above, you cannot use *народ*: the subject assumes individuals, not the groups.

Finally, *народ* may also mean "nation":

> Существуют индоевропейские языки и существуют народы, говорящие на этих языках. [Н. С. Трубецкой. *Мысли об индоевропейской проблеме (1938)]*
>
> Мы, русские, в первый раз празднуем нынешнюю годовщину; но и другие народы Европы не могут похвастаться перед нами в этом отношении. *[И. С. Тургенев. Речь о Шекспире (1864)]*
>
> Я пытался разгадать душу России и русского народа и написал ряд этюдов в этом направлении. *[Н. А. Бердяев. Автобиография (1917)]*

In this meaning (unlike the previous) *народ* may be used in plural.

Comment: spectacular!!!!

Answer (score 2):

> Россия — многонациональная страна, в ней живёт много разных *народов*.
>
> В эту комнату помещается много *людей*.
>
> В театре было мало *народа*.
>
> На собрание пришло не так много *людей*.

A bit more tough:

> Он вышел из *народа*.
>
> У ворот стал собираться трудовой *люд*.

Note that *народ* and *люди* can be used as synonyms in the slangish address:

> Народ (люди), может мне кто-нибудь помочь? Guys, can someone help me?

Comment: In the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 6th sentences you can use the other word as well without affecting the meaning.